# What is the default number of shards and replicas per Elasticsearch index as of ES 7.8?

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I can't find this information anywhere in the Elasticsearch documentation. I know it was 5 shards and 1 replica per index in the previous versions. Is is still like this? Where can I find this information?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

Comment: @KumarV thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Refer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html)

Deafult is 1 shard and 1 replica.

Comment: Thank you, Gibbs

Comment: Happy coding kirgol. You can find all index related setting in that page.